# Access apache server of virtual system in host system

Tags: apache, virtual-machine

I have installed centOS 6.3 as guest in win7 system using VMware. Apache server is created in centOS and it is working fine. But I want to access this apache server in host (win7) system.
Is it possible to access the apache server installed in guest system from the host system ?

Answer (score 0):

Use bridged networking.

1. Go to the *Network* tab
2. Select the network mode in VMWare as Bridged Network
3. Ensure that you have the proper firewall settings on host and guess.
4. Save the settings
5. Start the VM Again
6. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed the network mode to Bridged Network. But still it is not accessed from the host system. what should be firewall settings?

Comment: you can start with disabling the firewalls on both the host and the guest just to check if the firewall is indeed the problem. If it is indeed a firewall issue, you would need to open the apache port you want to access on the guest for all IPs (or the ones you want to allow access